# How to get diff of two ArrayList of Object in java

Tags: java

I have a list of employees and some method is adding/deleting the employee or editing the attributes of employees.

```
employee{id, name, age, grp}
```

where id is identifier.

I am trying to get all the differences between old list and modified list as per below format:

[image: Format of the output]

I tried *ObjectDifferBuilder* which is a java tool from github( https://github.com/SQiShER/java-object-diff ) like below:

```
//actionDataList - Action list for printing the diffs at the end of process
DiffNode diff = ObjectDifferBuilder.buildDefault().compare(newList, oldList);

diff.visit(new DiffNode.Visitor() {
    @Override
    public void node(DiffNode node, Visit visit) {
        String fieldName = "emp.";

        if (node.hasChanges() && !node.hasChildren()) {
            node.canonicalSet(newAe, node.canonicalGet(newAe) + "*");
        }

        if (!(node.getPath() == null || node.getPath().getLastElementSelector().toHumanReadableString().isEmpty())) {
            fieldName += node.getPath().getLastElementSelector().toHumanReadableString();

            Object baseValue = node.canonicalGet(oldList);
            Object workingValue = node.canonicalGet(newList);

            if (baseValue == null && workingValue instanceof String) {
                //for new values inserted
                actionDataList.add(new ActionData(fieldName, "", String.valueOf(workingValue)));
            } else if (workingValue == null && baseValue instanceof String) {                   
                // for old values deleted
                actionDataList.add(new ActionData(fieldName, String.valueOf(baseValue), ""));
            }
        }
    }
});
```

But still not getting proper output.

Comment: Did you tried debugging it?

Comment: What is `ObjectDifferBuilder`  and `DiffNode` ? You are using classes that are not from the JDK so it is a bit complicated to get the idea. Then you use a `Visitor`, that is also unknown. Can you be a bit more specific about those classes ? And also about the collections used to store those values to begin with. Try to [edit] this with a [mcve] with and input/output example too.

Comment: Are you trying to get some sort of intersection between two lists.

Comment: Yes, I tried debugging it. I added JAVA third party plugin info name from which ObjectDifferBuilder and DiffNode are referred.
@saurabh I am trying to get intersect but in some descriptive form.

Comment: The documentation you linked says that "Ordered lists are currently not properly supported (they are just treated as Sets). While this is something I definitely want to add before version 1.0 comes out, its a pretty big task and will be very time consuming. ... ..."

Comment: @aussie Yes, I need some suggestions for doing it another way. Currently, I am writing my own logic to print it manually but I am afraid I can cover all the scenarios like update/delete/insert in new list. So, shared the problem for some efficient solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I did a workaround like below. Hope this helps someone. (refer comments in code)

```
Map<String, Employee> entityById = 
oldList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Employee::getId, 
Function.identity())); //changed oldList to Map

  for (Employee entity : newList) //iterate new list to check the old values
  {
     if (entityById.containsKey(entity.getId())) // check for updated record
     {
        printActionRecord(entityById.get(entity.getId()), entity, actionDataList,"UPDATED");
        entityById.remove(entity.getId());
     }
     else // check for newly inserted record
     {
        printActionRecord(entityById.get(entity.getId()), entity, actionDataList,"INSERTED");
     }
  }
  if (!entityById.isEmpty()) // check for deleted record from new list( but existing in oldlist)
  {
     entityById.forEach((key, entity) -> {
        printActionRecord(entityById.get(entity.getId()), entity, actionDataList,"DELETED");
     });
  }
```

Above, I can calculated that which record is updated/Created/Deleted in New List. After I find this, I am passing that record with the old record(in case of update only) to get the difference. by `DiffNode diff = ObjectDifferBuilder.buildDefault().compare(newobj, oldobj);` which gives me a record for each change in field.

```
//actionDataList - Action list for printing the diffs at the end of process
DiffNode diff = ObjectDifferBuilder.buildDefault().compare(newObject, oldObject);

diff.visit(new DiffNode.Visitor() {
@Override
public void node(DiffNode node, Visit visit) {
    String fieldName = "emp."; //it should be a variable for each type of field
    if (!(node.getPath() == null || node.getPath().getLastElementSelector().toHumanReadableString().isEmpty())) {
        fieldName += node.getPath().getLastElementSelector().toHumanReadableString();

        Object baseValue = node.canonicalGet(oldObject);
        Object workingValue = node.canonicalGet(newObject);

        if (baseValue == null && workingValue instanceof String) {
            //for new values inserted
            actionDataList.add(new ActionData(fieldName, "", String.valueOf(workingValue)));
        } else if (workingValue == null && baseValue instanceof String) {                   
            // for old values deleted
            actionDataList.add(new ActionData(fieldName, String.valueOf(baseValue), ""));
        } else { // print updates
            actionDataList.add(new ActionData(fieldName, String.valueOf(baseValue), String.valueOf(workingValue))); 
        }
    }
}
});
```

Then, we can print the actionDataList values.

```
for(ActionData a: actionDataList){
    System.out.println("Field:"+ a.getFieldName()+ " Old Value:"+a.getOldValue()+"  NewValue:"+a.getNewValue());
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you need to refine what you are attempting to do.

You want the differences between two lists, where one list is generated from changes to the original list.  Except, they aren't really lists, they are lists of structured records (like database tables).

What does it mean to (emp.age, DELETE, 33)?  Does that mean that all employees with an age of 33 are removed?  Is it actually part of a specific employee's removal that spans 3 lines?

One way to force yourself to find out is to write an Interface, called `ListChange` and have its subclasses encapsulate the configuration of the change.  Then you could take a `List` and apply a `DeleteChange` to the `List` and see if you achieve your desired output.

Once you have such a structure, you almost have all the information you need, but it will be in the wrong format.  Instead of simply applying the change, add a few modifications to store the original record and the changed record, but only if the record is going to be changed.  That will give you your "records changed".

To chain these together, getting the correct output will require one more element, the "starting" record.  That way you compare the "changed record" for the operation to the "starting" record for the operation.  If you changed the record back to its starting record, you should discard the change entry.

Comment: What does it mean to (emp.age, DELETE, 33)?
It is a logged message saying that that employee record is removed in new list. DELETE is not for emp atrributes only. It is for whole emp record which was removed recently. And it actually like this
(emp.age, DELETE, 33, "")

Comment: @Moksh emp.age seems to be part of an employee record.  Wouldn't the whole employee record be emp.* ?

Comment: @Moksh Well, if you are logging each fields' change, the first step would be to build something that associates the various field changes with the single record change.

Comment: I did not understand "build something that associates the various field changes with the single record change" but as you see in my answer, I can calculated that which record is updated/Created/Deleted in New List. After I find this, I am passing that record with the old record(in case of update only) to get the difference. by `DiffNode diff = ObjectDifferBuilder.buildDefault().compare(newobj, oldobj);` which gives me a record for each change in field.